# Shared Sessions between Node Apps?

Tags: node.js, express, redis, session-state

I currently have two separate node apps running on two different ports but share the same backend data store.  I need to share users sessions between the two apps so that when a user logs into through one app, their session is available and they appear to logged into the other app.  In this case, its' a public facing website and an administrative backend.

Our setup is the following:

- node with express
- passport is being used to handle auth with Local Strategy
- we're using connect-redis to allow us to share sessions via redis.
- our domains look like this: www.mydomain.com and adm.mydomain.com

The config for for session stuff (and redis) is the same for both apps:

```
session: {
    options: {
        secret: "my secret",
        cookie: {
            domain: "mydomain.com",
            maxAge:1000*60*60*24
        }
    },
    redis: {
        host: 'my host',
        maxAge: 86400000,
        secret: "my secret"
    }
}
```

The config for session stuff in app.js looks like this:

```
if ( app.settings.env === "production" ) {
    session.options.store = new RedisStore(session.redis);
}
app.use(express.session(session.options));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session({ secret: 'a different secret' }));
```

**What I expect it to do**: Allow us to see the same session id in the cookie between the two apps.

*So my question is*: How do I set up express, redis and passport so that you can have sessions shared across different subdomains?

Comment: I think you might need to specify the cookie domain as `".mydomain.com"` -- note the leading `.`.

Comment: without a "*"? We used "*.mydomain.com" yesterday in a test and that didn't seem to work. 

I'll give this a try this morning and see what the result is.

Comment: You entered a `*`, right? In that case, yeah, just the leading dot. I think that's what makes a cookie readable from different sub-domains. Let me know and I could supply it as an answer.

Comment: So it turns out using ".mydomain.com" didn't actually work either. We're still looking... Thanks for the input though, Linus.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?  Is it even possible?

Comment: The solution will lie in the code which generates and stores the session I'd. Redis itself is just storing and retrieving what it is told to. However, you could use redis' MONITOR command to see the sets and gets. I suspect it will show each app setting new sessions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe a bit outdated, but at this time, Express-session can recognise domain option for cookie. According to source:

```
function session(options){
  var options = options || {}
  //  name - previously "options.key"
    , name = options.name || options.key || 'connect.sid'
    , store = options.store || new MemoryStore
    , cookie = options.cookie || {}
      ...
```

And this is for setting cookie:

```
var Cookie = module.exports = function Cookie(options) {
  this.path = '/';
  this.maxAge = null;
  this.httpOnly = true;
  if (options) merge(this, options);
  ...
```

So, something like this will work for current 1.10.1 master:

```
secret: "my secret",
    cookie: {
        domain: "mydomain.com",
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  I'm no longer on the project and not working in Node right meow, but this is excellent news to have.

Answer (score 2):

Express-session does not seem to recognize the "domain" option for cookies hence your problem.  The cookie storing the session id is automatically tied to the domain for each app and so it cannot be shared.

One option is to write your own single-sign-on module to share sessions across webapps.  It would probably live in an app.use() declaration fairly early in the execution order and would simply create a separate cookie (which would be cross-domain), create a separate SSO session id, and store the SSO id in this new cookie.  Afterwards, you simply cross-populate req.session and req.sso-session as needed.